# Multiple linear regression scikit-learn and statsmodel

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I'm attempting to use multiple linear regression on a data set using scikit-learn, but I am having trouble with getting the correct coefficients. I'm using the Lake Huron data which can be found here:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html

and after transforming it, I have the following set of values:

```
         x1        x2        y
0  0.202165  1.706366  0.840567
1  1.706366  0.840567  0.694768
2  0.840567  0.694768 -0.291031
3  0.694768 -0.291031  0.333170
4 -0.291031  0.333170  0.387371
5  0.333170  0.387371  0.811572
6  0.387371  0.811572  1.415773
7  0.811572  1.415773  1.359974
8  1.415773  1.359974  1.504176
9  1.359974  1.504176  1.768377
...  ...       ...       ...
```

using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(nvalues, columns=("x1", "x2", "y"))
result = sm.ols(formula="y ~ x2 + x1", data=df).fit()

print(result.params)
```

yields

```
Intercept   -0.007852
y2           1.002137
y1          -0.283798
```

which are the correct values, but if I end up using scikit-learn I get:

```
a = np.array([nvalues["x1"], nvalues["x2"]])
b = np.array(nvalues["y"])

a = a.reshape(len(nvalues["x1"]), 2)
b = b.reshape(len(nvalues["y"]), 1)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(a, b)

print(clf.coef_)
```

I get `[[-0.18260922  0.08101687]]`.

For completeness my code

```
from sklearn import linear_model

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

def Main():
    location = r"~/Documents/Time Series/LakeHuron.csv"
    ts = pd.read_csv(location, sep=",", parse_dates=[0], header=0)

    #### initializes the data ####
    ts.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1, inplace=True)

    x = ts["time"].values
    y = ts["LakeHuron"].values

    x = x.reshape(len(ts), 1)
    y = y.reshape(len(ts), 1)

    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(x, y)

    diff = []
    for i in range(0, len(ts)):
        diff.append(float(ts["LakeHuron"][i]-regr.predict(x)[i]))

    ts[3] = diff

    nvalues = {"x1": [], "x2": [], "y": []}

    for i in range(0, len(ts)-2):
        nvalues["x1"].append(float(ts[3][i]))
        nvalues["x2"].append(float(ts[3][i+1]))
        nvalues["y"].append(float(ts[3][i+2]))

    df = pd.DataFrame(nvalues, columns=("x1", "x2", "y"))
    result = sm.ols(formula="y ~ x2 + x1", data=df).fit()

    print(result.params)

    #### using scikit-learn ####
    a = np.array([nvalues["x1"], nvalues["x2"]])
    b = np.array(nvalues["y"])

    a = a.reshape(len(nvalues["x1"]), 2)
    b = b.reshape(len(nvalues["y"]), 1)

    clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(a, b)

    print(clf.coef_)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: Actually, I would say, `[[-0.18260922  0.08101687]]` (with intercept `[-0.02583547]` as given by `print(clf.intercept_)` ) are the correct values. R gives the same values. And, in fact, `statsmodels.api.OLS` also gives the same values (to try, do the following (replacing each ; with newline): `import statsmodels.api as sm2;import statsmodels.tools.tools as smtools;a2 = smtools.add_constant(a);result2 = sm2.OLS(b,a2).fit();print(result2.params)`). Just `statsmodels.formula.api.ols` shows these different values above.

Comment: The book I'm trying to replicate the result from has similar result to those displayed by statsmodels.api. I wanted to use scikit learn since I've had very good success with the AR(1) examples and wanted to expand this to AR(p) and MA(q) models and eventually to ARIMA(p,d,q) models

Comment: You were right. Problem was with the dataset resulting from incorrect reshape() of the ndarray. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
a = np.array([nvalues["x1"], nvalues["x2"]])
```

as it does not sort the data the way you intend. Instead it will generate a dataset

```
x1_new    x2_new
-----------------
 x1[0]     x1[1]
 x1[2]     x1[3]
[...]
 x1[94]    x1[95]
 x2[0]     x2[1]
[...]
```

Try instead

```
ax1 = np.array(nvalues["x1"])
ax2 = np.array(nvalues["x2"])
ax1 = ax1.reshape(len(nvalues["x1"]), 1)
ax2 = ax2.reshape(len(nvalues["x2"]), 1)
a = np.hstack([ax1,ax2])
```

There is probably a cleaner way to do that, but this way it works. The regressions now also give all the correct result.

EDIT: 
The cleaner way is to use `transpose()`:

```
a = a.transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

as per @Orange suggestion, I've changed the code to something I thing is more efficient:

```
#### using scikit-learn ####
a = []
for i in range(0, len(nvalues["x1"])):
    a.append([nvalues["x1"][i], nvalues["x2"][i]])

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(nvalues["y"])

a = a.reshape(len(a), 2)
b = b.reshape(len(nvalues["y"]), 1)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(a, b)

print(clf.coef_)
```

Which is a similar to the example on the scikit-learn site for simple regression